# React Native number of views count

Tags: react-native, count

I am currently working on a mobile app, being developed using react native and expo, where I need to keep track of number of views on a React Native View Component inside a React Native ScrollView Component. The number of views should be the similar to the youtube number of views. Any leads would be really appreciated.

Comment: Please add some code example to help us understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: did you find any solution to this @Hamza Iqbal ?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to store the number of time a specific view was hit (similar to YouTube) you could call a small function at the **componentDidMount** of that class. If you need to have it stored in the back end, you make your API call (I guess a simple function in the back-end increasing the current **viewCounter** would do).

If you need to display that number, you either can get it from back-end on the initialization of that view (componentDidMount is always a good option) or you can get it before calling the view (i.e. previous screen) and pass it as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

What you'r saying leave us with some blind side, but here's what I suggest:
in your export use this:

```
export default function nameOfThePage() {
const [views, setViews] = useState(0);
```

Call your database api where you're saving those records:

```
api.get('views')
.then(response => setViews(response.data.views)
```

and Setup your view:

```
<View style={setup your style}>
  <Text>{Views}</Text>;
</View>
```